# Por que não é recomendado usar "_" (underscore) em HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Já vi gente recomendando nunca usar `_` (*underscore*) em HTML e CSS. Ao invés disso, deveríamos dar preferência para `-`.

Exemplo:

```html
// Errado
<div id="minha_div" class="minha_classe"></div>

// Certo
<div id="minha-div" class="minha-classe"></div>
```

Por que existe essa recomendação?

Comment: Creio que hoje seje por nostalgia ou por costume antigo, não existe uma padronização oficial no W3C especificando isso

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A especificação de 1996 do CSS1 não permitia underscore em nomes de classes ou IDS, a não ser que elas estivessem "escapadas"

```css
p.#minha\_id {
  color: #fff;
}
```

O CSS2 (publicado em 1998) proibiu o uso do underscore. Uma errata posterior (2001) tornou o uso novamente permitido.

Hoje em dia praticamente todos browsers aceitam o underscore, mas a recomendação de não utilizar se mantém.

Comment: `Mas a recomendação de não utilizar se mantém` Mas não há nenhum motivo particular então?

Comment: @Andrey O motivo é esse: não há como garantir com certeza de que o navegador que o usuário está usando suporta underscore, apesar de todo navegador moderno dar suporte.

Comment: A especificação do CSS1 já é maior de idade - se você usa *underscores* no seu CSS e o navegador do usuário tiver problemas com isso, o problema é composto pelo usuário e pelo navegador, não pelo seu CSS. De qualquer forma, +1 pela resposta - eu jamais descobriria isso sem tê-la visto.

Answer (score 23):

Para complementar a resposta do @Beterraba, vou deixar uma **opnião**, sobre o assunto:

Além das especificações oficias CSS utilizarem *dashes* (traços), acredito que dashes é recomendável também por questões de convenções de código, exemplo:

**pseudo-elementos:** `first-letter`, `first-line` ...
**pseudo-classes:** `:first-child`, `:nth-child` ...
**propriedades:** `text-decoration`, `background-color`, e etc...

Observe que a segunda opção abaixo, parece mais bem escrita conforme a linguagem

```css
.minha_classe:first-letter {font-size:300%;}
.minha-classe:first-letter {font-size:300%;}
```

Pode ser difícil notar neste código simples, mais imagine em centenas ou milhares de linhas escritas na primeira maneira.

Agora imagine quando utilizamos **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** por exemplo, para adicionar uma classe específica ao código, exemplo:

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 minha_classe"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 minha-classe"></div>
```

Novamente parece melhor utilizar dash.

*Agora uma curiosidade não relacionada a dúvida de CSS, conforme esta matéria **[Dashes vs Underscores](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/)**, até pouco tempo atrás, o Google tratava palavras separadas por underscore (css_html) como uma única palavra e palavras separadas por dash (css-html) como palavras distintas. É por isso que é muito comum quando trabalhamos com url amigável utilizar dash ao invés de underscore.*

Comment: Bem colocado. Assim fica mesmo bem mais uniforme.

Answer (score -3):

Estou trabalhando com a metodologia da BEM e estou gostando muito, código legível é tudo!

Um simples resumo:

A BEM sigla para Block Element Modifier (Bloco Elemento Modificador), sugere uma estrutura para nomear as classes da sua folha de estilo baseando-se no elemento em questão. **Quando utilizamos a metodologia BEM é importante nos lembrarmos que ela zela pelo uso de ‘classes’ CSS e não IDs**, pelo fato das classes serem reutilizáveis.

**Block** : Um bloco pode ser simples ou composto (conter outros blocos internos), basicamente ele funciona como um container

```
.block {}
```

[image: block]

**Element** : Um elemento é uma “peça” do bloco. Temos o bloco como um container e os elementos são as peças inseridas nele, que desempenham funções específicas.

Um Input e um Search Button são elementos de um Search Block:

```
.block__element {}
```

[image: element]

**Modifier** : A metodologia BEM sugere que se for preciso criar um modificador, o mesmo deve ser feito adicionando-se dois hífens ( — ) após o nome do elemento ou bloco a ser modificado. O que nos dá uma estrutura com esse aspecto:

```
.block--modifier {}

.block__element--modifier {}
```

---

```
.header__navigation {}

.header__navigation--secondary {}
```

Partindo do pressuposto que sua navigation secundária provavelmente vai possuir os mesmos aspectos da anterior.

fonte: u.planb.com.br/blog/ti/metodologia-bem/